# How to "bind" services to specific channels (tcp, http, ipc) in a .NET Remoting server?

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I have a complex .NET Remoting server app that provides a couple of services. Clients can currently use tcp and http channels to connect to the server.

Now I need to implement some new administration services, but I want to restrict their availability to the local machine, i.e. I want to create an administration tool that can use these new services, but I do not want sensitive data to physically leave the server, so I need to restrict running the admin tool on the same server computer.

I thought about adding the new services and also registering the ipc channel with the server for use by the admin tool. Now comes the problem: how can I prevent remote clients connecting to these new admin services using the tcp or http channel? Can I say something like "register service x, implemented by class C in assembly A, usable only via ipc", "register service y, implemented by class D in assembly A, usable via tcp/http" in app.config (or using remoting infrastructure classes)?

It's the "usable only via ipc" part that baffles me. (And no, porting to WCF is not an option right now.)

Comment: I'm starting to work with .NET Remoting -- can you please tell me if you've ever tried to register more than one HttpChannel, and if so, have you been successful?

Comment: Dave, sorry for not checking in sooner. The answer is no, I have only used single tcp and http channels together in production. But let me fish out some older code and check it for you. Be back in a few minutes.

Comment: OK, so it looks like it does not work. ChannelServices.RegisterChannel() throws a "channel already registered" exception when trying to register the http channel twice, no matter if I set up remoting from configuration or code. I guess this is not supported (I have moved to WCF, so my intuition about Remoting may have gone rusty.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no overloads for RegisterWellKnownServiceType that allow you to specify which channel to register on, nor are there any methods on the IPCServerChannel to register a service, so none of that will work.

The best I can think of is writing a ChannelSink that filters your messages or provides security. These can be added to the constructor of your TcpChannel and HttpChannel to filter out admin only calls.

Comment: Thanks, Rob. Looks like I inadvertently painted myself in a corner with this one.

Comment: More like .NET Remoting painted you into a corner ;) When I first read your post, I thought it would be easy until I looked at the code.

Answer (score 1):

Get the IPAddress of the service calling it.  If it is anything other than 127.0.0.1 reject the call.